# Set colors to 2d scatter plot points - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm looking to build a `2D scatter plot` showing a Twitter environment regarding to the `number of tweets (x), the engagement gathered (y) and the number of followers (area)`. I've been categorizing the twitter accounts into `categories (category)`.

What I'm looking to do here is to set a `color to each category`. For instance, I'd like `category 1` to have a `green color`, the `second one yellow etc`.
I want them to have a precise color because afterwards, I will draw `one scatter for each category (individually)` and I want to `set the same color as in the global graph`.

Here is the data and what I've done so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([[0.02093863],
              [0.0732852 ],
              [0.0234657 ],
              [0.10072202],
              [0.04404332],
              [0.04151625],
              [0.0566787 ],
              [0.11696751],
              [0.01624549],
              [0.0465704 ],
              [0.07689531],
              [0.00830325],
              [0.0898917 ],
              [0.00866426],
              [0.04620939],
              [0.02310469],
              [0.04729242],
              [0.04765343],
              [0.06353791],
              [0.16967509],
              [0.01480144],
              [0.        ],
              [0.00469314],
              [0.15848375],
              [0.12490975],
              [0.06209386],
              [0.04909747],
              [0.48375451]])


y = np.array([[0.02379426],
              [0.        ],
              [0.02290457],
              [0.15219761],
              [0.25158697],
              [0.10492664],
              [0.13245242],
              [0.02621148],
              [0.0423237 ],
              [0.05317184],
              [0.1527853 ],
              [0.04502115],
              [0.03738906],
              [0.20284717],
              [0.06304946],
              [0.26262975],
              [0.10163784],
              [0.09668436],
              [0.24601169],
              [0.0474632 ],
              [0.02213749],
              [0.00489361],
              [0.32378162],
              [0.24242926],
              [0.01124397],
              [0.11000865],
              [0.18842167],
              [1.        ]])

category = np.array([[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1],
                     [2], [2], [2], [2],
                     [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3],
                     [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [5]])

area = np.array([[2.53481554e+00],
                 [2.08893232e+01],
                 [3.26197166e+02],
                 [6.12020523e+01],
                 [3.93659907e+01],
                 [2.79745908e+01],
                 [2.61818959e+02],
                 [1.27351576e+01],
                 [1.02919619e+01],
                 [4.01294894e+01],
                 [3.57622771e+01],
                 [5.48802834e+01],
                 [1.07408991e+02],
                 [1.50867334e+01],
                 [1.66748107e+01],
                 [4.67261178e+01],
                 [1.07806010e+01],
                 [4.09235280e+00],
                 [3.23723430e+00],
                 [7.05472758e+00],
                 [1.98509651e+00],
                 [0.00000000e+00],
                 [5.82091376e+01],
                 [3.54263376e+01],
                 [2.27522600e+01],
                 [1.76826289e+01],
                 [1.22465184e+01],
                 [1.00000000e+03]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=category, s=area, alpha=0.5)
ax.set_title("Global")
ax.set_xlabel("number tweets")
ax.set_ylabel("mean engagement")
plt.show()
```

Do you how could I replace my actual way of setting color in order to set specific color for each category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
colors = {1:'red',2:'blue',3:'green',4:'yellow',5:'pink'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.scatter(x, y, c=[colors[n[0]] for n in category], s=area, alpha=0.5)
ax.set_title("Global")
ax.set_xlabel("number tweets")
ax.set_ylabel("mean engagement")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]